# Wunderground api search bar

Tags: python, json, api

I'm currently writting a program that will search for the weather.
I'm trying to create an option where you can search  your location however it doesn't seem to be working.

```
  from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
  import json
  import re
  location = input('location you would like to know the weather for')

API_KEY = '<API-KEY>'
url = 'http://python-weather-api.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ python-weather-api' + API_KEY +'/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/'+ location +'.json'


response = urllib.request.Request(url)


def response as request(url)
json_string = response.read().decode('utf8')
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
location = parsed_json['location']['city']


temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
print("Current temperature in %s is: %s" % (location, temp_f))
response.close()
```

I keep on recieving this error

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet (reputation too low since I just joined SO), but regarding your "urllib is not defined" issue, that has to do with how you import the urlopen function.

Instead of:

```
urllib.urlopen(url)
```

try:

```
urlopen(url)
```

EDIT: Here's your code, fixed:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

location = input('location you would like to know the weather for')

API_KEY = '<API-KEY>'
url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/' + API_KEY + '/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/'+ str(location) +'.json'

response = urlopen(url)

json_string = response.read().decode('utf8')
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
location = parsed_json['location']['city']
temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
print("Current temperature in %s is: %s" % (location, temp_f))
```

Works fine for Tama and other cities in IA. Watch out though, place names like Des Moines won't work, because spaces aren't allowed in the URLs - you'll have to take care of that. (The example for the API suggests _ for spaces http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?MR=1). Good luck!

Comment: I have tried this however it comes back with an error of 

NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Comment: That's because you don't assign your urlopen(url) to anything. Hint: request = urlopen(url)

Comment: I don't have an error for urlopen . I have this as my error

      json_string = response.read().decode('utf8')
      NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Comment: I know. Because your program doesn't know what 'response' is. You haven't defined it. I assumed that it's the response you get from urlopen.  Right now, you open the url and throw the result away.

Comment: I've had a go at defining the 'response.' Look at my edit 2 please. 
Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer to include a working version of your code. Note the  `response = urlopen(url)` Also note that the Requtest import went out the window.

Comment: hi I still receive a key error on this line 

location = parsed_json['location']['city']

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you used a city with a space in it (see my previous comment)? Or a city outside of IA? You are only querying cities in Iowa "/q/IA" in your code.

Comment: Checked it again, works for the following example input: Tama, Des_Moines, Cedar_Rapids, Carroll. All places in Iowa (IA) of course.

Answer (score 1):

Hey not sure if you are still stuck on this but here is my wunderground project that should have what you're looking for https://github.com/Oso9817/weather_texts

Answer (score 0):

Where you have str.input, you need to use str(location).  Right now if you go into a python repl and type str, you will find out that it is a reserved keyword.  You want to use the variable location you are getting from the input of the user and not the str object.

Comment: ok thanks I just tried what you suggest and it seemed to solve the problem however I receive another problem that says 'urllib' is not defined.